# Cannot access model using controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, controller

I create new controller and models using php artisan command. And I tried to access model using controller but I get `Class 'Thankful' not found` error.

Controller code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Thankful;
class Thanks extends Controller
{
    public function hello(){

        $my_data = new Thankful;
        $data = $my_data->my_model();
        return view("thanks",compact('data'));
    }
}
```

Model Code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thankful extends Model
{
    public function my_model()
    {
        $data = "Thank You";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace of your `Thankful` model is incorrect:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Thankful;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Thanks extends Controller
{
    public function hello ()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: No worries, make sure to mark the answer as "correct" if it solved your issue!

Comment: I don't know why 2 people down vote this question. Did I make mistake by asking simple question?